# count(*) in each of previous 25 months separately

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database name "d" and there is table name "t"...
t has two columns id and month...

I have to calculate no of ids in each month.

actually, I am taking an input in $monthyear, now I want to store count(id) of previous 25 month in a $row

I use this type of commands

```
    $search = "SELECT * FROM `d`.`t` where id>2";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $search);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

please tell me a query which can do this trick and can you store it like

```
$row[0]="no of ids in the inputed month"
$row[1]="no of ids in the [inputed month - 1 month]"
$row[2]="no of ids in the [inputed month - 2 month]"
```

and so on....

note: both month and "years" do matter.

Answer (score 1):

If not all month has IDs , then you need to use a derived table. Something like this:

```
SELECT t.monthyear, COALESCE(COUNT(s.monthyear),0) as numOfID
FROM(SELECT '012016' as monthyear
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '022016' 
     ....) t
LEFT JOIN YourTable s
 ON(t.monthyear = s.monthyear)
GROUP BY t.monthyear
```

Comment: this will not work as i am taking an input of month and year like "04/2017" . and i have to start from this month to previous 25 month

Comment: We are not paid to write your code for you - sagi has given you a very complete answer to the question you asked.